# Interface for selecting based on two fields

Tags: website-design, web-app, selection

I have a web application that has several select lists, some of them are plural and some of them are singular and user should select just one item. In both cases users should be able to choose their item(s) based on two fields, e.g. Id, Name.

In the traditional desktop app, they usually have a field where user can enter the id and the name will appear in the label next to it. And a button that opens a search window where user can search by Id and Name.

I'm looking for a more modern approach that is appropriate for web and also is easy to implement. Actually, I was thinking about [Kendo MultiSelect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/), since I have used their components in other sections.

I should note that there might be hundreds of items, but user will choose only several.

[I'll be thankful if someone can edit the post and title.]

Comment: one field's content depends on other? If you've already worked something out, could you provide an screenshot or mockup?

Comment: Yes, I've used a multiselect with server-side filtering. So the user can type in code or part of the name and I'll filter the content.